# Why are images and tiff files looking jagged when tilted?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image][image][image][image]When I place an image or a tiff in illustrator where I've removed the background of an image in photoshop, the edges look jagged? Also the text looks jagged?

Comment: Could you possibly take a screenshot and share it here?  It's almost impossible to answer a question like this blind.

Comment: This is such a low-quality image that it's impossible to decipher the jagged tiffs from the rest of the art.

Comment: The bottom image seems very low resolution. All I can see is the pixels because it seems to have been zoomed in.  If you zoom in on raster images you will see the pixels!

Comment: @Ovaryraptor it's zoomed in to show the jagged edge. I'll take another screenshot of the pic on the website at 100%.

Comment: The one I just posted shows on the girl in the polaroid frame where her chin looks jagged/pixelated. This is at 100% from the website. It was created in illustrator, saved as a jpeg, optimized for web at 60% quality. The page is very image heavy so we had to save at 60% in order for the page to not take forever to load. I'm also wondering why the lettering looks pixelated.

Comment: The picture I just added with the carousel shows 4 small polaroid images at the bottom. They are super pixelated and jagged.

Comment: Are you zoomed in at 100%?

Comment: @Emilie I am not sure I understand your question? How can I be zoomed in at 100%? Wouldn't that be more than 100% if I zoomed in?

Comment: If you had currently been designing in the software, the % of zoom can create some artifacts but my understanding is these images were saved from a website so I provided an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that some items look more jagged than others because they may have been lower resolution in the first place (e.g. the placeholders for the polaroid vs. the type). Even if the whole thing was created in Illustrator, you are using pixel-based images in most of the layout and these items will always have their respective resolution. Additionally, the jaggedness will be more noticeable where you have highly contrasting values and this shows in your image (e.g. aqua or white on the brown tube looks terrible).

It also shows more when images are tilted simply because your images use pixels. Any diagonal will show more jaggedness than a straight horizontal or vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to:

### Rotated pixels

When rotating images in a vector based program like Illustrator or InDesign, you are not altering the original pixels of the images but instead you are literally rotating them.

Try to zoom all the way in and you can see the rotated pixels:

[image]

If the image is in high resolution the rotated pixels won't be visible on print, but they might not be rendered too nicely on screen. If the resolution of the image is low (72 ppi or below) the rotated pixels will become visible even at 100%.

I know it's convenient to use a vector based program for these kinds of collages (I often use InDesign myself), but the drawback is that the rendering of rotated and overlapped images won't be as smooth as in a pixel based program like Photoshop.

The best way to camouflage the "rotated pixels problem" would probably be to work at a higher resolution (using higher resolution images) and downscale on export.